# How to access API of an Express Mongodb server deployed on Vercel

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vercel

I am trying to host my node express server on vercel. The deployment was successful.

Here's the index.js file:

```
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require("mongodb");
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//imperial-motors-firebase-adminsdk.json

const serviceAccount = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_SERVICE_TOKEN);

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

// Middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

//Mongodb Connect
const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@cluster0.7xlcz.mongodb.net/?
retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1,
});

async function verifyAuthToken(req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers?.authorization?.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];

    try {
      const decodedUser = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);
      req.decodedEmail = decodedUser.email;
    } catch {}
  }
  next();
}

async function run() {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    const database = client.db("imperial");
    const userCollection = database.collection("users");
    const orderCollection = database.collection("orders");
    const carCollection = database.collection("cars");
    const reviewCollection = database.collection("reviews");
    console.log("db connected");

    //GET: Get all reviews
    app.get("/reviews", async (req, res) => {
      const cursor = reviewCollection.find({});
      const result = await cursor.toArray();
      res.send(result);
    });

    //GET: Get all Cars
    app.get("/cars", async (req, res) => {
      const cursor = carCollection.find({});
      const result = await cursor.toArray();
      res.send(result);
    });

    //Get: Car by Id
    app.get("/cars/:id", async (req, res) => {
      const id = req.params.id;
      const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
      const result = await carCollection.findOne(query);
      res.json(result);
    });

    //GET: Get all Orders
    app.get("/orders", verifyAuthToken, async (req, res) => {
      const requestingEmail = req.decodedEmail;
      if (requestingEmail) {
        const requestingUser = await userCollection.findOne({
          email: requestingEmail,
        });
        if (requestingUser.role === "admin") {
          const cursor = orderCollection.find({});
          const result = await cursor.toArray();
          res.send(result);
        }
      } else {
        res.status(403).json({ message: "You do not have permission." });
      }
    });

  } finally {
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Ah, here We Go!");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Listening at: ", port);
});
```

vercel.json looks like this:

```
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```
  "name": "imperial-server-side",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "start-dev": "nodemon index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^4.1.4"
  }
}
```

Here's my project structure:
[image]

I've also whitelisted IPs on MongoDB atlas where the database is stored. The production url [on vercel](https://imperial-motors-service.vercel.app/) returns a success message. But whenever I try to access one of the APIs such as /cars or /reviews it says it cannot get such API. What went wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "it cannot get such API"? Is there any error?